# how to use node-http-proxy inside AdonisJS controller

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy, adonis.js

I am trying to use node-http-proxy inside an AdonisJS controller, but I get the error

```
The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type function
```

The line causing the error is the `proxy.web(request, response, { target: urlToProxy });`

```
async proxy({ request, response }){
    var resource = await Resource.query().where('uri', request.url()).with('service.user').with('userSecurity').first()
    resource = resource.toJSON()
    if(!resource.service.active){
      return response.status(404).send(`Parent service '${resource.service.title}' is disabled`)
    }
    if(!resource.active){
      return response.status(404).send(`Resource is disabled`)
    }
    if(resource.userSecurity.length <= 0) {
      return response.status(403).send(`You are not permitted to access that resource. Contact ${resource.service.user.first_name} ${resource.service.user.last_name} (${resource.service.user.email})`)
    }

    var urlToProxy = url.resolve(resource.service.basepath, request.originalUrl())
    var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer()

    proxy.web(request, response, { target: urlToProxy });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got a bit closer but not a full fix. The getting close bit was to realise the http-proxy was delivering data via buffer so I had to do something like this

```
proxy.web(req, res, { target: data.service.basepath})
    proxy.on('error', function(err, req, res){
      console.log("There was an error", err)
    })

    proxy.on('proxyRes', async (proxyRes, request, response) =>{
      var body = new Buffer('')
      proxyRes.on('data', (data)=>{
        body = Buffer.concat([body, data])
      })

      proxyRes.on('end', ()=>{
        body = body.toString()
        try{
          res.send(body)
        }catch(err){
        }
      })
    });
```

However, I still could not get it to work as the controller was returning before http-proxy had completed the request.

In the end and probably for the best,  I wrote a stand alone proxy app and used the main app just to validate JWT tokens before they go through the Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, I wanted to do something similar and wrapped the proxy in a promise so we can wait for the proxy to return before responding with our response:

```
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    proxy.web(request.request, response.response, {
        target: urlToTarget
    }, (e) => {
        reject(e);
    });

    proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        let body = [];
        proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        proxyRes.on('end', function () {
            body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
});

const result = await prom;
response.body(result);
return response;
```

I thought I'd give you a complete answer for anyone else that comes across this.